# How to prove $3^{k-1}-1$ is divisible by $k$ if $k$ is a prime greater than $3$?

Tags: number-theory

I was playing around with numbers and noticed that $3^{k-1}$ is divisible by integer $k$ if $k$ is a prime greater than $3$. I was wondering how might I go proving this fact?

I haven't done any modular arithmetic before unfortunately and I have some feeling that knowing modular arithmetic would help me out here. If I weren't to use modular arithmetic, how would I prove this?

Comment: Hint:  this is true if you replace $3$ by any integer prime to $k$.

Comment: Ah, as you say you don't know anything about modular arithmetic...first of all, congratulations on a good observation.  Secondly, take a look at [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: Personally, I think the way one would come to a proof without using modular arithmetic, is via a combinatorial proof. This is, infact, how I came to the result long ago. It was even before I learnt modular arithmetic, so that made it really nice to know.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг But you were a prodigy. I don't think you can expect others to repeat your superhuman achievements

Comment: @WillJagy I agree. Olof Mellberg was too.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  note that the first set was 6-1 to Stephens, while the second set is currently 5-0 to Williams. Strange

Comment: @WillJagy Agreed Sir.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I'll look at that theorem

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you, I'll investigate the combinatorial route

Comment: This statement proves true: $$\because \forall k\in \mathcal{P}_{>3}, \ 3\nmid k : \mathcal{P} = \text{the set of prime numbers greater than $3$}$$

Comment: This works not just for primes, but also for some composite $k$. See https://oeis.org/A005935.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of Fermat Little Theorem.

Here is a nice little proof of this little theorem, in this case.

Let $X= \{ 1 \pmod{k}, 2 \pmod{k},..., k-1 \pmod{k} \}$. Then $f :X \to X$ defined by 
$$f(x)=3x \pmod{k}$$
Is a bijection. Therefore 
$$X=\{ 3\pmod{k}, 6 \pmod{k},..., 3k-3 \pmod{k} \}$$

Multiplying everything together you get that 
$$1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot (k-1) \equiv 3 \cdot 6 \cdot 9 \cdot ... \cdot (3k-3) \pmod{k}$$

Now, since $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot (k-1)$ has an inverse $\pmod{k}$, we can cancel it and get
$$1 \equiv 3^{k-1} \pmod{k}$$